# How to keep selected set of strings and remove all the other set of strings from main string using Regex.Replace?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove MEA1B4, WP and HIC from MEA1B4, SLI, CPR, WP, HIC using Regex.Replace and print as SLI, CPR.

For example in string1, SLI, CPR, string2, string3 I always wanted to keep SLI, CPR except all the other strings.

I have tried to do the above functionality using the pattern of .*(SLI\S*?CPR).* , Yet I only managed to replace the main string as SLI and couldn’t get full string as SLI, CPR

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't exactly a regex, but it works for what you described

```
function filterString(stringList, toKeep) {
    return stringList.split(", ")                 // split into array
        .filter(el => toKeep.includes(el))        // filter out all non matching elements
        .join(", ")                               // join back to a comma separated string
}
// call with
filterString("MEA1B4, SLI, CPR, WP, HIC", ["SLI", "CPR"])
```

Answer (score 0):

For RegExp, you can simply search for specific string.

```
const string = 'SLI, MEA1B4, CPR, WP, HIC' 

//'.' represents any single character in regex
// '|' represents the 'or' operator
const pattern = /(SLI|MEA1B4)./g   

string.replace(pattern, "")  //"  CPR, WP, HIC"
string.replace(pattern, "").trim()   //"CPR, WP, HIC"
```